# Trying to use Javascript array to display Random images in <div>

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, random

I'm not well know about javascripts, got this code from a website.
Using javascript to display random images from array in div
javascript working fine.
**But loaded images displays in random sizes**
**tried using css style and all css html image attributes to resize them but nothing works, as they are displayed directly through javascript**

want something to resize them directly in javascript

code main :

```
<script>    
           var arrayImg = new Array();
           arrayImg[0] = "a11.jpg";
           arrayImg[1] = "a12.jpg";


            getRandomImage(arrayImg, "");

          function getRandomImage(imgAr, path) {      
            path = path || 'images/'; // default path here
            var num = Math.floor( Math.random() * imgAr.length );
            var img = imgAr[ num ];
            var imgStr = '<img src="' + path + img + alt = "" >';
            document.writein(imgStr); 
            document.close();
            }

         </script>
```

code I used to resize image : **(but didn't work)** :

```
<script>    
           var arrayImg = new Array();
           arrayImg[0] = "a11.jpg";
           arrayImg[1] = "a12.jpg";


            getRandomImage(arrayImg, "");

          function getRandomImage(imgAr, path) {      
            path = path || 'images/'; // default path here
            var num = Math.floor( Math.random() * imgAr.length );
            var img = imgAr[ num ];
            var img.height = 4vw;
            var img.width = 20%;
            var imgStr = '<img src="' + path + img + img.height + img.width + alt = "" >';
            document.writein(imgStr); 
            document.close();
            }

         </script>
```

even tried using : (but still didn't work)

```
document.writeln('<td' + '><imgstr"' + height="180" width="160" border="0" ><' + '/td>');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few syntax error in `getRandomImage` function.

```
function getRandomImage(imgAr, path) {      
    path = path || 'images/'; // default path here
    var num = Math.floor( Math.random() * imgAr.length );
    var img = imgAr[ num ];

    /* 
        1. variable name should not contain . 
        2. the width and height value should be quoted and placed in "style" attribute
    */
    //var img.height = 4vw;
    //var img.width = 20%;
    var imgHeight = '4vw';
    var imgWidth = '20%';

    /* closed string quotations and placed data in the right attribute */
    var imgStr = '<img src="' + path + img + '"'
               + ' style="height:' + imgHeight + ';width:' + imgWidth + ';'
               + ' alt="">';
    document.writein(imgStr); 
    document.close();
}
```

Comment: used  document.write(imgStr); instead of  document.writein(imgStr); in your given code and worked, thank you so much +rep for you :D

Answer (score 1):

You have several places where you didn't close quotation marks.

In code main:

```
var imgStr = '<img src="' + path + img + '"' + ' alt = "" >';
```

In resize code

```
var imgStr = '<img src="' + path + img + '" height="' + img.height + '" width="' + img.width + '" alt = "" >';
```